# How do I not get kicked for targeting a single opponent?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I've been repeatedly kicked for targeting a single opponent. The issue is that sometimes this happens in a 2v2 and the other team is down to 1 person. Once my team starts going after that one guy, we sometimes get kicked.

[image]

Comment: This may be something you should talk with [Nintendo Support](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13181) about.

Comment: This looks like something that should only occur in Free-For-All, not Team Battle.

Comment: Wasn't this fixed in an update? Try checking if an update is available on your 3DS. I could be mistaken.

Comment: @TechnoSam The date of this question was months ago. That could be the case now. I'm not sure I moved on to the Wii u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not happen at all, if this continues you will have no choice but to contact Nintendo Support. Their number is: +1 800-255-3700